# how to return a string value from an event handler to another file in same package java

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

in my program  when i select a radion button,i  need to get the corresponding value and the file name in the InputStream openContentStream() function of the next file

SampleNewWizard.java

```
package amma.wizards;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard;
import org.eclipse.ui.INewWizard;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.*;
import org.eclipse.jface.operation.*;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.*;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;

import java.io.*;

import org.eclipse.ui.*;
import org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE;

  /**
 * This is a sample new wizard. Its role is to create a new file 
 * resource in the provided container. If the container resource
 * (a folder or a project) is selected in the workspace 
 * when the wizard is opened, it will accept it as the target
 * container. The wizard creates one file with the extension
 * "mpe". If a sample multi-page editor (also available
 * as a template) is registered for the same extension, it will
 * be able to open it.
 */

 public class SampleNewWizard extends Wizard implements INewWizard {
private SampleNewWizardPage page;
private ISelection selection;

    /**
 * Constructor for SampleNewWizard.
 */
public SampleNewWizard() {
    super();
    setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
}

/**
 * Adding the page to the wizard.
 */

public void addPages() {
    page = new SampleNewWizardPage(selection);
    addPage(page);
}

/**
 * This method is called when 'Finish' button is pressed in
 * the wizard. We will create an operation and run it
 * using wizard as execution context.
 */
public boolean performFinish() {
    final String containerName = page.getContainerName();
    final String fileName = page.getFileName();
    // setFileExtension("xml");
    IRunnableWithProgress op = new IRunnableWithProgress() {
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException {
            try {
                doFinish(containerName, fileName, monitor);
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                throw new InvocationTargetException(e);
            } finally {
                monitor.done();
            }
        }
    };
    try {
        getContainer().run(true, false, op);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Throwable realException = e.getTargetException();
        MessageDialog.openError(getShell(), "Error", realException.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * The worker method. It will find the container, create the
 * file if missing or just replace its contents, and open
 * the editor on the newly created file.
 */

private void doFinish(
    String containerName,
    String fileName,
    IProgressMonitor monitor)
    throws CoreException {
    // create a sample file
    monitor.beginTask("Creating " + fileName, 2);
    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IResource resource = root.findMember(new Path(containerName));
    if (!resource.exists() || !(resource instanceof IContainer)) {
        throwCoreException("Container \"" + containerName + "\" does not exist.");
    }
    IContainer container = (IContainer) resource;
    final IFile file = container.getFile(new Path(fileName));
    try {
        InputStream stream = openContentStream();
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.setContents(stream, true, true, monitor);
        } else {
            file.create(stream, needsPreviousAndNextButtons(), monitor);
        }
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    monitor.worked(1);
    monitor.setTaskName("Opening file for editing...");
    getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            IWorkbenchPage page =
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
            try {
                IDE.openEditor(page, file, true);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
            }
        }
    });
    monitor.worked(1);
}

/**
 * We will initialize file contents with a sample text.
 * @param contents 
 */

public static InputStream openContentStream() {
    String contents =
        "This is the initial file contents for *.ej file that should be word-sorted in the Preview page of the multi-page editor";
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes());
}

private void throwCoreException(String message) throws CoreException {
    IStatus status =
        new Status(IStatus.ERROR, "amma", IStatus.OK, message, null);
    throw new CoreException(status);
}

/**
 * We will accept the selection in the workbench to see if
 * we can initialize from it.
 * @see IWorkbenchWizard#init(IWorkbench, IStructuredSelection)
 */
public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection) {
    this.selection = selection;
}
}
```

SampleNewWizardPage.java

```
package amma.wizards;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IContainer;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewWizardMessages;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.SelectionButtonDialogFieldGroup;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.IDialogSettings;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ContainerSelectionDialog;

/**
 * The "New" wizard page allows setting the container for the new file as well
 * as the file name. The page will only accept file name without the extension
 * OR with the extension that matches the expected one (ej).
*/

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class SampleNewWizardPage extends WizardPage {
private Text containerText;

private Text fileText;

private ISelection selection;
private SelectionButtonDialogFieldGroup fMethodStubsButtons;
IType type;

/**
 * Constructor for SampleNewWizardPage.
 * 
 * @param pageName
 */
public SampleNewWizardPage(ISelection selection) {
    super("wizardPage");
    setTitle("Multi-page Editor File");
    setDescription("This wizard creates a new file with *.ej extension that can be opened by a multi-page editor.");
    this.selection = selection;
    String[] buttonNames3= new String[] {"type","channel","inherited"   };
    fMethodStubsButtons= new SelectionButtonDialogFieldGroup(SWT.CHECK,  buttonNames3, 1);
       fMethodStubsButtons.setLabelText(NewWizardMessages.NewClassWizardPage_methods_label);
}

/**
 * @see IDialogPage#createControl(Composite)
 */
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    container.setLayout(layout);
    layout.numColumns = 3;
    layout.verticalSpacing = 9;
    Label label = new Label(container, SWT.NULL);
    label.setText("&Container:");

    containerText = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
    GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    containerText.setLayoutData(gd);
    containerText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            dialogChanged();
        }
    });


    Button button = new Button(container, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Browse...");
    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            handleBrowse();
        }
    });
    label = new Label(container, SWT.NULL);
    label.setText("&File name:"); 
    fileText = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);

    gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);


    fileText.setLayoutData(gd);
    fileText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            dialogChanged();
        }
    });
    Label separator = new Label (container, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    label = new Label(container, SWT.NULL);
    label.setText("&Select:"); 
     final Button mrButton = new Button(container, SWT.RADIO);
     mrButton.setText("Channel");
     final Button mrsButton = new Button(container, SWT.RADIO);
     mrsButton.setText("Type");
     mrButton.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {
                StringBuffer buf= new StringBuffer();
                final String lineDelim= "\n";
                if(mrButton.getSelection() == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("channel");
                    String contents = "hai";
                    //SampleNewWizard.openContentStream(contents);
                    buf.append("channel "+getFileName());
                    buf.append("()");
                    buf.append(lineDelim);
                    buf.append("{");
                    buf.append(lineDelim);
                    buf.append("}");
                    buf.toString();
                //  try {
                          //type.createMethod(buf.toString(), null, false, null);
                    //} catch (JavaModelException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch  block
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    //}
                    }
               IDialogSettings dialogSettings= getDialogSettings();
                if (dialogSettings != null) {
                    IDialogSettings section= dialogSettings.getSection(getFileName());
                    if (section == null) {
                    section= dialogSettings.addNewSection(getFileName());
            }
              }
            }
     });

     mrsButton.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {

                if(mrsButton.getSelection() == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("type");
                }
            }
        });

    initialize();
    dialogChanged();
    setControl(container);
}


/*  private void createMethodStubSelectionControls(Composite container,int nColumns) {
    Control labelControl= fMethodStubsButtons.getLabelControl(container);
    LayoutUtil.setHorizontalSpan(labelControl, nColumns);

    DialogField.createEmptySpace(container);

    Control buttonGroup= fMethodStubsButtons.getSelectionButtonsGroup(container);
    LayoutUtil.setHorizontalSpan(buttonGroup, nColumns - 1);

}*/

/*  public boolean istype() {
    return fMethodStubsButtons.isSelected(0);
}

/**
 * Returns the current selection state of the 'Create Constructors' checkbox.
 *
 * @return the selection state of the 'Create Constructors' checkbox
 */
/*public boolean ischanel() {
    return fMethodStubsButtons.isSelected(1);
}*/

/**
 * Returns the current selection state of the 'Create inherited abstract  methods'
 * checkbox.
 *
 * @return the selection state of the 'Create inherited abstract methods' checkbox
 */
/*public boolean isCreateInherited() {
    return fMethodStubsButtons.isSelected(2);
}*/
/*public void setMethodStubSelection(boolean type, boolean chanel, boolean createInherited, boolean canBeModified) {
    fMethodStubsButtons.setSelection(0, type);
    fMethodStubsButtons.setSelection(1, chanel);
    fMethodStubsButtons.setSelection(2, createInherited);

    fMethodStubsButtons.setEnabled(canBeModified);
}*/






/**
 * Tests if the current workbench selection is a suitable container to use.
 */

private void initialize() {
    if (selection != null && selection.isEmpty() == false
            && selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
        IStructuredSelection ssel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
        if (ssel.size() > 1)
            return;
        Object obj = ssel.getFirstElement();
        if (obj instanceof IResource) {
            IContainer container;
            if (obj instanceof IContainer)
                container = (IContainer) obj;
            else
                container = ((IResource) obj).getParent();
             containerText.setText(container.getFullPath().toString());
        }
    }
    fileText.setText("");
}

/**
 * Uses the standard container selection dialog to choose the new value for
 * the container field.
 */

private void handleBrowse() {
    ContainerSelectionDialog dialog = new ContainerSelectionDialog(
            getShell(), ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(),  false,
            "Select new file container");
    if (dialog.open() == ContainerSelectionDialog.OK) {
        Object[] result = dialog.getResult();
        if (result.length == 1) {
            containerText.setText(((Path) result[0]).toString());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Ensures that both text fields are set.
 */

private void dialogChanged() {
    IResource container = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
            .findMember(new Path(getContainerName()));
    String fileName = getFileName();

    if (getContainerName().length() == 0) {
        updateStatus("File container must be specified");
        return;
    }
    if (container == null
            || (container.getType() & (IResource.PROJECT | IResource.FOLDER)) == 0) {
        updateStatus("File container must exist");
        return;
    }
    if (!container.isAccessible()) {
        updateStatus("Project must be writable");
        return;
    }
    if (fileName.length() == 0) {
        updateStatus("File name must be specified");
        return;
    }
    if (fileName.replace('\\', '/').indexOf('/', 1) > 0) {
        updateStatus("File name must be valid");
        return;
    }
    int dotLoc = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (dotLoc != -1) {
        String ext = fileName.substring(dotLoc + 1);
        if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("ej") == false) {
            updateStatus("File extension must be \"ej\"");
            return;
        }
    }
    updateStatus(null);
}

private void updateStatus(String message) {
    setErrorMessage(message);
    setPageComplete(message == null);
}

public String getContainerName() {
    return containerText.getText();
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileText.getText();
}
/*protected void createTypeMembers(IType type, ImportsManager imports, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
    boolean doMain= istype();
    boolean doConstr= ischanel();
    boolean doInherited= isCreateInherited();
    //createInheritedMethods(type, doConstr, doInherited, imports, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));

    if (doMain) {
        StringBuffer buf= new StringBuffer();
        final String lineDelim= "\n"; // OK, since content is formatted afterwards //$NON-NLS-1$
    //  if (isAddComments()) {
            String comment= CodeGeneration.getMethodComment(type.getCompilationUnit(), type.getTypeQualifiedName('.'), "main", new String[] { "args" }, new String[0], Signature.createTypeSignature("void", true), null, lineDelim); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
            if (comment != null) {
                buf.append(comment);
                buf.append(lineDelim);
            }
        //}
        buf.append("public static void main("); //$NON-NLS-1$
        //buf.append(imports.addImport("java.lang.String")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        buf.append("[] args) {"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        buf.append(lineDelim);
        final String content= CodeGeneration.getMethodBodyContent(type.getCompilationUnit(), type.getTypeQualifiedName('.'), "main", false, "", lineDelim); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        if (content != null && content.length() != 0)
            buf.append(content);
        buf.append(lineDelim);
        buf.append("}"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        type.createMethod(buf.toString(), null, false, null);
    }

    //IDialogSettings dialogSettings= getDialogSettings();
    //if (dialogSettings != null) {
    //  IDialogSettings section= dialogSettings.getSection(PAGE_NAME);
    //  if (section == null) {
    //      section= dialogSettings.addNewSection(PAGE_NAME);
    //  }
        //section.put(SETTINGS_CREATECONSTR, ischanel());
        //section.put(SETTINGS_CREATEUNIMPLEMENTED, isCreateInherited());
    }

    //if (monitor != null) {
        //monitor.done();
//  }*/
}
```

//}

Comment: help me plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: Nobody is going to try and make sense of such a huge wall of code. Tell us exactly where you think the problem is and please explain what you are doing and what you want in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setter and getter

SampleNewWizard.java

```
 .............
 public InputStream openContentStream() {
    String contents =
        "This is the initial file contents for *.ej file that should be word-sorted in the Preview page of the multi-page editor";
    if(page.getContent()!=null) {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(page.getContent().getBytes());
    }
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes());
}
  ............
```

SampleNewWizardPage.java

```
package amma.wizards;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IContainer;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewWizardMessages;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.SelectionButtonDialogFieldGroup;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.IDialogSettings;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ContainerSelectionDialog;



@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class SampleNewWizardPage extends WizardPage {
private Text containerText;

private Text fileText;

private ISelection selection;
private SelectionButtonDialogFieldGroup fMethodStubsButtons;
IType type;
StringBuffer buf= new StringBuffer();

private String content;
public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

/**
 * Constructor for SampleNewWizardPage.
 * 
 * @param pageName
 */
public SampleNewWizardPage(ISelection selection) {
    super("wizardPage");
    setTitle("Multi-page Editor File");
    setDescription("This wizard creates a new file with *.ej extension that can be opened by a multi-page editor.");
    this.selection = selection;
    String[] buttonNames3= new String[] {"type","channel","inherited"   };
    fMethodStubsButtons= new SelectionButtonDialogFieldGroup(SWT.CHECK, buttonNames3, 1);
    fMethodStubsButtons.setLabelText(NewWizardMessages.NewClassWizardPage_methods_label);
}

/**
 * @see IDialogPage#createControl(Composite)
 */
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    container.setLayout(layout);
    layout.numColumns = 3;
    layout.verticalSpacing = 9;
    Label label = new Label(container, SWT.NULL);
    label.setText("&Container:");

    containerText = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
    GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    containerText.setLayoutData(gd);
    containerText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            dialogChanged();
        }
    });


    Button button = new Button(container, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Browse...");
    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            handleBrowse();
        }
    });
    label = new Label(container, SWT.NULL);
    label.setText("&File name:"); 
    fileText = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);

    gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);


    fileText.setLayoutData(gd);
    fileText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            dialogChanged();
        }
    });
    Label separator = new Label (container, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    label = new Label(container, SWT.NULL);
    label.setText("&Select:"); 
     final Button mrButton = new Button(container, SWT.RADIO);
     mrButton.setText("Channel");
     final Button mrsButton = new Button(container, SWT.RADIO);
     mrsButton.setText("Type");

     mrButton.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {

                final String lineDelim= "\n";
                if(mrButton.getSelection() == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("channel");
                    //String contents = "hai";
                    //SampleNewWizard.openContentStream(contents);
                    int dotLoc = getFileName().lastIndexOf('.');
                    String Name = getFileName().substring(0,dotLoc);
                    buf.append("channel "+Name);
                    buf.append("()");
                    buf.append(lineDelim);
                    buf.append("{");
                    buf.append(lineDelim);
                    buf.append("}");
                    buf.toString();
                    setContent(buf.toString()); 
                //  try {
                        //type.createMethod(buf.toString(), null, false, null);
                    //} catch (JavaModelException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    //}
                    }
               IDialogSettings dialogSettings= getDialogSettings();
                if (dialogSettings != null) {
                    IDialogSettings section= dialogSettings.getSection(getFileName());
                    if (section == null) {
                    section= dialogSettings.addNewSection(getFileName());
            }
              }
            }
     });

     mrsButton.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {
                final String lineDelim= "\n";
                if(mrsButton.getSelection() == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("type");
                    int dotLoc = getFileName().lastIndexOf('.');
                    String Name = getFileName().substring(0,dotLoc);
                    buf.append("Type "+Name);
                    buf.append("()");
                    buf.append(lineDelim);
                    buf.append("{");
                    buf.append(lineDelim);
                    buf.append("}");
                    buf.toString();
                    setContent(buf.toString()); 
                }
            }
        });

    initialize();
    dialogChanged();
    setControl(container);
}








/**
 * Tests if the current workbench selection is a suitable container to use.
 */

private void initialize() {
    if (selection != null && selection.isEmpty() == false
            && selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
        IStructuredSelection ssel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
        if (ssel.size() > 1)
            return;
        Object obj = ssel.getFirstElement();
        if (obj instanceof IResource) {
            IContainer container;
            if (obj instanceof IContainer)
                container = (IContainer) obj;
            else
                container = ((IResource) obj).getParent();
            containerText.setText(container.getFullPath().toString());
        }
    }
    fileText.setText("");
}

/**
 * Uses the standard container selection dialog to choose the new value for
 * the container field.
 */

private void handleBrowse() {
    ContainerSelectionDialog dialog = new ContainerSelectionDialog(
            getShell(), ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(), false,
            "Select new file container");
    if (dialog.open() == ContainerSelectionDialog.OK) {
        Object[] result = dialog.getResult();
        if (result.length == 1) {
            containerText.setText(((Path) result[0]).toString());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Ensures that both text fields are set.
 */

private void dialogChanged() {
    IResource container = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
            .findMember(new Path(getContainerName()));
    String fileName = getFileName();

    if (getContainerName().length() == 0) {
        updateStatus("File container must be specified");
        return;
    }
    if (container == null
            || (container.getType() & (IResource.PROJECT | IResource.FOLDER)) == 0) {
        updateStatus("File container must exist");
        return;
    }
    if (!container.isAccessible()) {
        updateStatus("Project must be writable");
        return;
    }
    if (fileName.length() == 0) {
        updateStatus("File name must be specified");
        return;
    }
    if (fileName.replace('\\', '/').indexOf('/', 1) > 0) {
        updateStatus("File name must be valid");
        return;
    }
    int dotLoc = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (dotLoc != -1) {
        String ext = fileName.substring(dotLoc + 1);
        if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("ej") == false) {
            updateStatus("File extension must be \"ej\"");
            return;
        }
    }
    updateStatus(null);
}

private void updateStatus(String message) {
    setErrorMessage(message);
    setPageComplete(message == null);
}

public String getContainerName() {
    return containerText.getText();
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileText.getText();
}

}
```